# Как сохранить картинку из ресурсов андроид приложения?

Tags: java, android

Как сохранить картинку из ресурсов андроид приложения на телефон? То есть хочу чтобы по нажатии кнопки определенная картинка из ресурсов сохранялась на телефон. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

1) Получаешь картинку из ресурсов следующим образом:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

2) Далее сохраняешь ее в памяти телефона:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream out = null;
File file = new File(path, "imagename.jpg"); 

try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory()` разве это путь не до внешнего(External) хранилища?

Comment: Не работает что то у меня, может потому что у меня нету sd карты на телефоне. А как сделать чтобы картинка сохранялась в память телефона к примеру в папку "загрузки"?

Answer (score 0):

Картинка будет лежать в ресурсах приложения, просто скопируй её в другую папку по выбору пользователя.